# Web application to receive anonymous pdf submissions from students

Tags: file-management, forms, file-sharing, anonymization

On an online exam, the teacher likes to receive the students' submissions (pdf document) anonymously without knowing their emails and names. In that case, I tried making a Google form that will receive only the exam roll and registration number from the students. But when I add a File Upload option, the form starts asking to sign up and consequently collecting the students' names associated with the Gmail accounts!

So, what are the most effective and easy-to-use online tools/platforms to receive the students' submissions anonymously? Note that self-hosting type things are not preferable, and I'm looking for free service. The platform may collect data, but the receiver should not find out the senders name and email.

(It was asked on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/155434/196564). But it's off-topic and closed there.)

Comment: Is self-hosting an option? Must it be free, or is there a budget? Btw: when it comes to "anonymously" and "not collecting data", corps like Google, MS etc (aka "GAFAM") are certainly out of the question.

Comment: No, self-hosting type things are not preferable, and looking for free service. The platform may collect data, but the receiver should not find out the senders name and email.

Comment: A 'teacher'? Like, a faculty member at a school? If so, does the school (or district) have any technology? Maybe an FTP server configured with a dedicated folder for this class?

Comment: What about an FTP Server with a "/pub/incoming" directory that is writable but not listable to anonymous users? This is a very old concept.

Comment: @bsmither FTP server seems good. But currently, the teacher doesn't have it. It would be better if you could suggest some other simpler easy-to-use tools.